# Create a bridge between a tunnel and ethernet device

Tags: linux, vpn, tunnel, bridge, debian-wheezy

I have a Raspberry pi with Debian wheezy. There are three connections exists:

```
eth0: native usb ethernet, connected to the router.
eth1: plug-in usb ethernet adapter
tun0: tunnel created by openconnect vpn client
```

Now, I want to create a bridge between `eth1` and `tun0`, so that all the traffic from `eth1` are routed to the VPN. There is no application running on the OS needs the VPN connection.

```
  ------------------------
  |  OS Local --> eth0 --|--> router
  |                      |
  |   Debian Wheezy      |
  |                      |
--|--> eth1 --> tun0 ----|--> vpn server
  ------------------------
```

I did some research and it turns out that `tun0` is a layer 3 device while `eth1` is a layer 2 device. They can't talk to each other directly.
The first thing come to my mind is if I can create a `tun1` from `eth1` and connect `tun1` and `tun0`. But is it possible? How can I do this?

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Current route table after vpn connected:

```
default dev tun0  scope link 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  metric 202 
44.33.22.11 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.14 
172.18.2.0/24 dev tun0  scope link 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.14  metric 202
```

Comment: Do you really need this??? Please post your routing table, *sudo ip route show*.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae route table posted.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae sorry but where can I find the answer?

Comment: I have just published my answer to your query, please come see it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement *policy routing*, which means having two routing tables. We shall not touch the `main` routing table which is already correctly setup. If you have enabled IPv4 forwarding, it will automatically push the packets from eth1 through your OpenVPN.

First, we need to learn how your OpenVP sets up the routing table. To this, end, start the OpenVPN client from the command line:

```
    sudo openvpn --config YourConfigFile.conf
```

(or `YourConfigFile.ovpn`, whichever you use). The last lines will tell you how it sets up the new routing table, for instance in my case it says:

> Tue Jul 14 18:58:07 2015 /sbin/ip route add My.Server.Public.IPaddress/32 via 192.168.105.1
>
> Tue Jul 14 18:58:07 2015 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.73.5
>
> Tue Jul 14 18:58:07 2015 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.73.5
>
> Tue Jul 14 18:58:07 2015 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.73.0/24 via 10.8.73.5
>
> Tue Jul 14 18:58:07 2015 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.73.0/24 via 10.8.73.5
>
> Tue Jul 14 18:58:07 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed

The routes above should be introduced into an executable file, except that some of these numbers are peculiar to this particular instance of the VPN. OpenVPN however provides useful environmental variables which will hold the values of the interfaces used above, and which come in very handy: in this specific case, they are

```
      route_net_gateway -> 192.168.105.1
      route_vpn_gateway -> 10.8.73.5
```

Thus the lines you need to add to a file (let's call it `/etc/openvpn/route_up.sh`) are:

```
 /sbin/ip route add Your.OpenVPN.Server.IPAddress/32 via $route_net_gateway table vpn
 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via $route_vpn_gateway table vpn
 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via $route_vpn_gateway table vpn
 /sbin/ip route add Remote.LAN.Net/24 via $route_vpn_gateway table vpn
 /sbin/ip route add 172.18.2.0/24 via $route_vpn_gateway table vpn
```

Remember to substitute, in the above, the IP address of your remote server, and of its local LAN **if you use it**; if you are just using the OpenVPN to obtain an IP of your server, then you do not need the next to the last statement at all. Remember to make the file executable, `chmod 700 route_up.sh`.

Also, you will also have to create a new file, `/etc/openvpn/route_down.sh`, also executable, which tears down exactly the same routes (just change `add` to `del`).

Now we need to tell your OpenVPN to avoid implementing the routes, because we will do this manually: in your YourConfigFile.conf, add the following lines:

```
        route-nopull
        up /etc/openvpn/route_up.sh
        down /etc/openvpn/route_down.sh
```

Lastly, we need to setup the different routing table for the VPN. Add a new routing table, let's call it `vpn`:

```
       echo 200 vpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Now we introduce a rule:

```
     ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/24 table vpn
```

where I assumed that the network behind `eth1` is `10.0.0.0/24`, if it is not please change accordingly.

Lastly, you will have to introduce a MASQUERADE iptables rule:

```
      iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This is it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: I would love clarification on Your.OpenVPN:server.IPAddress and Remote.LAN.Net. the first is "public ip" of server? and what is the other? Thanks!

Comment: @LennartRolland **1):** Yes.  **2):** It is the LAN in which the OpenVPN server is immersed, sometimes you want to have access to it. For instance, suppose you have setup an OpenVPN server **at home**, and you connect to it when you are away. Then you will certainly want to connect to your OpenVPN server **and** to its LAN (which appears as *remote* to you, when you are away from home). If instead you are using an OpenVPN server provided by a commercial enterprise, for instance to allow you to bypass geo-restrictions, then you have no interest to contact the LAN in which the server resides.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Thank you that cleared it up perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to make a dual ethernet VPN passthrough, which the data comes in through `eth1`, and `eth0` connects to the router (outbound to the Internet).

You can use iptables to redirect your `eth1` traffic to `tun0`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```